# Problem with tkz-tab and its the PSTricks package equivalent

Tags: pstricks, pspicture, tkz-tab

My code:(use tkz-tab)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,newcent}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ /1, $g'(x)$ /1, $g(x)$ /3.5} 
{$-\infty$,$a$,$1$,$3$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,+,0,-,0,+  }
\tkzTabVar{+/$+\infty$, -/$m-\dfrac{1}{4}$ , +/$g(1)$, -/$m$, +/$+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result compiling:

[image]

Question:

1. How to move `m-1/4` lower than `m`? It means

[image]
2. Does PSTricks has the command or package(I don't know) the same as **tkz-tab**? Assume without any the command or package, so how to create it only use the `pspicture` environment?

Comment: You're right, it seems I misunderstood. I've added a new code (leaving the previous one, as it might be of interest to some). Is it better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, is this what you want? Note I replaced $\dfrac{1}{4}$ with $\mfrac{1}{4}$ (medium sized fraction from `nccmath`) , as I think that, used as a numerical coefficient, it looks nicer. The level alignment of `m-\mfrac{1}{4}`  and `m` is obtained adding a `\vphantom{\mfrac{1}{4}}` to the latter, so the boxes containing both minima have the same height.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, newcent}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ /1, $g'(x)$ /1, $g(x)$ /3.5}
{$-\infty$,$a$,$1$,$3$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,+,0,-,0,+ }
\tkzTabVar{+/$+\infty$, -/$m-\mfrac{1}{4}$ , +/$g(1)$, -/$m\vphantom{\mfrac 14}$, +/$+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:
It seems I misundertood the requirement. I hope the following code is more like you want (same preamble):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit{$x$ /1, $g'(x)$ /1, $g(x)$ /3.5}
{$-\infty$,$a$,$1$,$3$, $+\infty$}
\tkzTabLine{,-,0,+,0,-,0,+ }
\tkzTabVar{+/$+\infty$, -/$m-\mfrac{1}{4}$ , +/$g(1)$, -/\raisebox{4ex}{$m\vphantom{\mfrac{1}4}$}, +/$+\infty$}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: I see it seem was not changed. " m-1/4 " = " m "

Comment: Both *m*s are now at the same level, using a `\vphantom{\mfrac{1}{4}` for the rightmost *m*

Comment: You can edit your answer to show what you say. My english is not good.

Comment: I've added some explanations. Is that clearer?

Comment: `\smash[t]{\vphantom{\mfrac{1}{4}}}` seems better. Or `\dfrac`, of course, if `\dfrac` is used in the other place.

Comment: @Bernard See edited question. My aim is to set "m" at that position. Seem you misunderstood.

Comment: @egreg: you're perfectly right. I also tried to smashh from *m*, but it's not so good

Comment: @Bernard Again, thank you for your answer and you should improve it perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new `tablvar` package (documentation in French):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[tikz]{tablvar}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tablvar}{4}
\hline
x & -\infty && a && 1 && 3 && +\infty \\
\hline
g'(x) && - & 0 & + & 0 & - & 0 & + & \\
\hline
\variations{
  \mil{g(x)} &
  \haut{+\infty} &&
  \bas{m-\dfrac{1}{4\mathstrut}} &&
  \haut{g(1)} &&
  \bas{m} &&
  \haut{+\infty}
}
\hline
\end{tablvar}
\]

\end{document}
```

Removing the `tikz` option makes the package rely on PSTricks.

[image]

If you want to easily move the *m* up (which I can't see the necessity of), raise it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[tikz]{tablvar}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tablvar}{4}
\hline
x & -\infty && a && 1 && 3 && +\infty \\
\hline
g'(x) && - & 0 & + & 0 & - & 0 & + & \\
\hline
\variations{
  \mil{g(x)} &
  \haut{+\infty} &&
  \bas{m-\dfrac{1}{4\mathstrut}} &&
  \haut{g(1)} &&
  \bas{\raisebox{2ex}{$m\mathstrut$}} &&
  \haut{+\infty}
}
\hline
\end{tablvar}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but you should see edited question! My aim is to set "m" at that position.

Comment: @chishimotoji Added. Probably there are more features in the package documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Out of topic!
For polynomials and rational functions with minimum one rational zero
we can do the factorization and finding the (only) rational roots with the help of
the xintexpr and polexpr packages. Then the table is build automatic.

So we can type for e.g. in the document

```
\poldef zf1(x):=(-1/4)(x^2-4x+3)(x-2)^2(x^2+1)(x^2+2);
\PolReduceCoeffs{zf1}
Given is the derivative:
\[f^{\prime}:t \mapsto \PolTypeset[t]{zf1} = \typesetFactors[t]{zf1} \]

\medskip
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\VZTabelle[f][t][zf1]
```

Here is the code for a full example.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,svgnames,x11names,dvipsnames]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{polexpr}
\usepackage{xfp,xparse,expl3,xstring}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator={\,},output-decimal-marker={,},exponent-product=\cdot,per-mode=fraction,product-units=single,
input-product=*,output-product=\cdot,unit-mode=text,quotient-mode=fraction,locale=DE,range-phrase = { bis }}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\let\funk\PolToExpr
\let\STZeroL\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\XcalcR}{sO{8}m}{%  calculates #3 and rounds to #2 decimals; non formating: for formated output use \Xcalc not \XcalcR
\PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\xinttheiexpr[#2]reduce(#3)\relax}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Xcalc}{t+stDsO{2}m}{% calculates #5, rounds to #4 decimals (trailing zeros are supressed) and typesets the number with num-macro formatting
\IfBooleanT{#1}{\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr #6\relax}{}{+}{+}}%  or as fraction, reduced or not reduced and with #3=D is a boolean in displaystyle
\IfBooleanTF{#2}%
  {\IfBooleanT{#3}{\displaystyle}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}%
        {\xintSignedFrac{\xinttheexpr #6\relax}}%
        {\xintSignedFrac{\xinttheexpr reduce(#6)\relax}}%
    }%
    {\num{\PolDecToString{\xintREZ{\xinttheiexpr[#5]reduce(#6)\relax}}}}%
}


\newcommand{\NullStellen}[1]{%
   \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}}}
   \do
   {x_{##1} = \Xcalc{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{#1}{##1}}%
   \xintifForLast{}{; }}%
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\hackNst}{O{nt}D(){x}m}{%
    \xintifboolexpr{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#3}=0}{}{%
    \xintiloop [1+1]
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\xintbracediloopindex
    \xintdefvar #2\tmp = \PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{#3}\tmp;
    \xintdefvar #1\tmp = \PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#3}\tmp;
    \ifnum\xintiloopindex<\numexpr\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#3}\relax
    \repeat
    }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GenFloatSturmZeros}{ssO{9}D(){x}m}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {%
    \PolToSturm{#5}{#5}%
    \PolSturmIsolateZeros**{#5}%
    \PolEnsureIntervalLengths{#5}{-#3}%
    \IfBooleanF{#2}{\hackNst(#4){#5}}%
    }%
    {%
    \PolGenFloatVariant{#5}%
    \PolToSturm{#5}{#5}%
    \PolSturmIsolateZeros**{#5}%
    \PolEnsureIntervalLengths{#5}{-#3}%
    }%
}


\def\smstext{steigt}%
\def\smftext{fällt}
\def\HPtext{Hochpkt.}
\def\TPtext{Tiefpkt.}
\def\SPtext{Terrassenpkt.}
\def\DiffRowtxt{f^{\prime}}
\def\lueckColor#1{\colorlet{lckColor}{#1}}
\lueckColor{BrickRed}
\def\Poltxt{\textcolor{lckColor}{Polstelle}}
\def\Lueckentxt{\textcolor{lckColor}{Def.-Lücke}}
\def\Notdeftxt{\textcolor{lckColor}{\diagup}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\VZTabelle}{sO{f}O{x}O{#21}!d()}{%
\IfValueTF{#5}{%
                \PolGCD{#4}{#5}{commonfactorA}%
                \poldef erwzaehlerA(x) := (#4(x)#5(x))/(commonfactorA(x))^2 ;%
                \poldef gekuerzterNenner(x) := #5(x)/commonfactorA(x) ;%
                \PolGCD{erwzaehlerA}{commonfactorA}{commonfactorB}%
                \poldef commonfactorC(x) := commonfactorA(x)/commonfactorB(x) ;%
                \poldef erwzaehler(x) := erwzaehlerA(x)commonfactorC(x) ;%
              }%
              {%
                \poldef erwzaehler(x) := #4(x) ;%
                \poldef commonfactorC(x) := 1 ;%
              }%
    \PolToSturm{erwzaehler}{erwzaehler}%
    \PolSturmIsolateZeros**{erwzaehler}%
    \PolEnsureIntervalLengths{erwzaehler}{-9}%
\begin{tabular}{*{\XcalcR{2+2*\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{erwzaehler}}}{>{$}c<{$}}}
 \IfBooleanF{#1}{\toprule}
    \IfValueTF{#5}{\Firstrow{erwzaehler}{#3}{#5}}{\Firstrow{erwzaehler}{#3}{1}}
    \IfValueTF{#5}{\VZmakerows{erwzaehler}{#5}{#4}{#3}}{\VZmakerows{erwzaehler}{1}{#4}{#3}}
    \IfValueTF{#5}{\Diffrow{\DiffRowtxt}{erwzaehler}{#3}{#5}}{\Diffrow{\DiffRowtxt}{erwzaehler}{#3}{1}}
    \IfValueTF{#5}{\Graphrow{#2}{erwzaehler}{#5}}{\Graphrow{#2}{erwzaehler}{1}}
 \IfBooleanF{#1}{ \\ \bottomrule}
\end{tabular}%
}

\def\leadcoef#1{\xintifboolexpr{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}=1}{}{\Xcalc{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}}\cdot}}

\def\nst#1#2{\Xcalc*{\STZeroL{#1}{#2}}}

\def\VZfktwertL#1#2{\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr #1(\xinttheexpr \STZeroL{#1}{#2}-0.001\relax)\relax}{-}{0}{+}}

\def\VZfktwertR#1#2{\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr #1(\xinttheexpr \STZeroL{#1}{#2}+0.001\relax)\relax}{-}{0}{+}}

\def\VZfktwert#1#2{\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr #1(\STZeroL{#1}{#2})\relax}{-}{0}{+}}

\def\tabfactor#1#2#3#4{%
        \xintifboolexpr{\STZeroL{#1}{#2}=0}%
                {#4}%
                {(#4\Xcalc+*{-\STZeroL{#1}{#2}})
                  \xintifboolexpr{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#1}{#2}=1}%
                    {%
                        \xintifboolexpr{commonfactorC(\STZeroL{#1}{#2})=0}%
                            {^{0}}%
                            {}%
                    }%
                    {%
                        \xintifboolexpr{commonfactorC(\STZeroL{#1}{#2})=0}%
                                            {%
                                                ^{0}
                                            }%
                                            {%
                                                ^{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#1}{#2}}
                                            }%
                    }%
                }%
}


\def\MonotonieL#1#2{\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr #1(\XcalcR{\STZeroL{#1}{#2}-0.001})\relax}{\text{\smftext}}{0}{\text{\smstext}}}

\def\MonotonieR#1#2{\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr #1(\XcalcR{\STZeroL{#1}{#2}+0.001})\relax}{\text{\smftext}}{0}{\text{\smstext}}}

\def\Extrema#1#2{\xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr (#1(\XcalcR{\STZeroL{#1}{#2}-0.001}))*(#1(\XcalcR{\STZeroL{#1}{#2}+0.001}))\relax >0}%
        {\text{\SPtext}}%
        {%
          \xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr #1(\xinttheexpr \STZeroL{#1}{#2}-0.001\relax)\relax>0}%
                {\text{\HPtext}}%
                {\text{\TPtext}}%
        }%
   }%


\NewDocumentCommand{\VZtabfac}{st{>}mmm}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr (-\STZeroL{#3}{#4}+\STZeroL{#3}{#5})^\xintifboolexpr{commonfactorC(\STZeroL{#3}{#4})=0}{0}%
    {\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#3}{#4}}\relax}{-}{0}{+}}%
    {%
      \IfBooleanTF{#2}%
        {%
            \xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr (-\STZeroL{#3}{#4}+\STZeroL{#3}{#5}+0.001)^\xintifboolexpr{commonfactorC(\STZeroL{#3}{#4})=0}{0}%
            {\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#3}{#4}}\relax}{-}{0}{+}%
        }%
        {%
            \xintifSgn{\xinttheexpr (-\STZeroL{#3}{#4}+\STZeroL{#3}{#5}-0.001)^\xintifboolexpr{commonfactorC(\STZeroL{#3}{#4})=0}{0}%
            {\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#3}{#4}}\relax}{-}{0}{+}%
        }%
    }%
}


\newcommand{\VZmakerows}[4]{%
     \xintifboolexpr{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}<0}%
                {%
                    \xintSignedFrac{\xintIrr{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}}} & -
                    \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}}}
                        \do {  & - & - } \\ \midrule
                }%
                {}%
    \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}}}
    \do
        {\tabfactor{#1}{##1}{#3}{#4} & \VZtabfac{#1}{##1}{1}%
            \xintFor* ##2 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}}}
                \do
                {  &
                    \IfDecimal{#2}%
                       {\VZtabfac*{#1}{##1}{##2}}%
                       {%
                        \xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr #2(\STZeroL{#1}{##2})\relax = 0}%
                            {\Notdeftxt}
                            {\VZtabfac*{#1}{##1}{##2}}%
                        }%
                    &   \VZtabfac>{#1}{##1}{##2}
                }
     \\ \midrule
     }
}


\newcommand{\Firstrow}[3]{%
    #2 & -\infty<#2<\nst{#1}{1} & \IfDecimal{#3}{#2=\nst{#1}{1}}%
            {\xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr #3(\STZeroL{#1}{1})\relax = 0 }%
                    {\textcolor{lckColor}{#2=\nst{#1}{1}}}%
                    {#2=\nst{#1}{1}}%
            }%
\xintifboolexpr{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}>1}{%
   \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}-1}}
   \do
   {%
        & \nst{#1}{\xinttheexpr ##1\relax}<#2<\nst{#1}{\xinttheexpr ##1+1\relax} &
            \IfDecimal{#3}%
                {#2=\nst{#1}{\xinttheexpr ##1+1\relax}}%
                {\xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr #3(\STZeroL{#1}{\xinttheexpr ##1+1\relax})\relax = 0 }%
                    {\textcolor{lckColor}{#2=\nst{#1}{\xinttheexpr ##1+1\relax}}}%
                    {#2=\nst{#1}{\xinttheexpr ##1+1\relax}}%
                }%
   }%
   }%
   {}%
    & \nst{#1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#1}}<#2<+\infty\\ \midrule
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\Diffrow}{mmmm}{%
    #1(#3)
   \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#2}}}
   \do
   {& \VZfktwertL{#2}{##1} &
        \IfDecimal{#4}%
            {\VZfktwert{#2}{##1}}%
            {%
                \xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr #4(\STZeroL{#2}{##1})\relax = 0}%
                {\Notdeftxt}
                {\VZfktwert{#2}{##1}}%
            }%
   }%
    & \VZfktwertR{#2}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#2}} \\ \midrule
}


\newcommand{\Graphrow}[3]{%
    \text{G}_{#1}
   \xintFor* ##1 in {\xintSeq{1}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#2}}}
   \do
   {& \MonotonieL{#2}{##1} & \IfDecimal{#3}{\Extrema{#2}{##1}}{%
        \xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr #3(\STZeroL{#2}{##1})\relax = 0}%
            {%
                    \xintifboolexpr{\xinttheexpr gekuerzterNenner(\STZeroL{#2}{##1})\relax =0}%
                        {\text{\Poltxt}}
                        {\text{\Lueckentxt}}
            }%
            {\Extrema{#2}{##1}}%
        }%
   }%
    & \MonotonieR{#2}{\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#2}}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin of code for factorization %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Counter for LOOP over the roots of f
\newcount\zeroCount
% Set counter to 1
\zeroCount=1

% Proof if a root is "0" then only write x and not (x-0) ...
% factor the roots like (x-x_1) if x_1>0, (x+x_1) if x_1<0
\newcommand{\factorZeros}[1]{%
    \xintifZero{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{#1}{\the\zeroCount}}%
        {\varname}
        {\left(\varname\xintiiifSgn{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{#1}{\the\zeroCount}}{+}{-}{-}
        \xintSignedFrac{\xintIrr{\xintAbs{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroLeft{#1}{\the\zeroCount}}}}\right)
        }
}

% Don't write multiplicity of a root in case it is =1
\newcommand{\ignoreMultiplicityOne}[1]{%
    \xintifOne{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#1}{\the\zeroCount}}{}{\PolSturmIsolatedZeroMultiplicity{#1}{\the\zeroCount}}
}

% Hide leading coefficient if leading coefficient is + or - 1.
\newcommand{\hideLeadingCoeff}[1]{%
\xintifOne{\xintAbs{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}}}%
    {\xintiiifSgn{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}}{-}{}{}}
    {\xintSignedFrac{\xintIrr{\PolLeadingCoeff{#1}}}}
}

% Typeset polynomial as factors of its rational roots: f(x)=a_n(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n)(quotient function)
\newcommand{\typesetFactors}[2][x]{%
\def\varname{#1}%
% #1 = function
\PolToSturm{#2}{#2}%
\PolSturmIsolateZeros**{#2}%
\xintifboolexpr{\PolDegree{#2}<2}{\xintifboolexpr{\PolDegree{#2}<1}{\PolTypeset[\varname]{#2}}{\left(\PolTypeset[\varname]{#2}\right)}}{%
\xintifboolexpr{\PolDegree{#2}=\PolDegree{#2_norr}}{\PolTypeset[\varname]{#2}}{%
\poldef #2_rat(x) := #2(x)/#2_norr(x);
\poldef #2_norr_VZ(x) := \xintSgn{\PolLeadingCoeff{#2_norr}}#2_norr(x);
\PolToSturm{#2_rat}{#2_rat}%
\PolSturmIsolateZeros**{#2_rat}%
%
\hideLeadingCoeff{#2}%
% Loop over all rational zeros of the function f = #2 ;  #2_rat is the part with only rational zeros
% #2_rat is defined as #2(x)/#2_norr(x), and #2_norr is the part of #2 with no rational roots (square-free version is #2_irr )
    \loop
        \factorZeros{#2_rat}^{\ignoreMultiplicityOne{#2_rat}}%
        \advance \zeroCount 1
        \ifnum \zeroCount<\xinttheexpr\PolSturmNbOfIsolatedZeros{#2_rat}+1\relax
    \repeat
\xintifZero{\PolDegree{#2_norr}}%
{}%
{\left(\PolTypeset[\varname]{#2_norr_VZ}\right)}%
}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End of code for factorization %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\smstext{$\nearrow$}
\def\smftext{$\searrow$}
\def\HPtext{H}
\def\TPtext{T}
\def\SPtext{Ter.}
\def\DiffRowtxt{f^{\prime}}
\def\Poltxt{\textcolor{lckColor}{Pol}}
\def\Lueckentxt{\textcolor{lckColor}{Loch}}


\begin{document}

\poldef zf1(x):=(-1/4)(x^2-4x+3)(x-2)^2(x^2+1)(x^2+2);
\PolReduceCoeffs{zf1}
Given is the derivative:
\[f^{\prime}:t \mapsto \PolTypeset[t]{zf1} = \typesetFactors[t]{zf1} \]

\medskip
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\VZTabelle[f][t][zf1]
\bigskip

\poldef zf1(x):=(x^2-4x+3)*(x-2);
\PolReduceCoeffs{zf1}
\poldef nf1(x):=(x^2+1)(x-2)^2;
\PolReduceCoeffs{nf1}
Given is the derivative:
\[f^{\prime}:x \mapsto \frac{\PolTypeset{zf1}}{\PolTypeset{nf1}} = \frac{\typesetFactors{zf1}}{\typesetFactors{nf1}}\]

\medskip
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\VZTabelle[f][x][zf1](nf1)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Thank you for your problem expansion. But truly I don't understand anything. hihi :-))

Comment: very impressive but you seem to be using some development version of `polexpr` which finds rational roots as current version `0.6` does not have the double starred `\PolSturmIsolateZeros**`.... I am very jealous!

Comment: @jfbu yes, you are right. I actually forgot that.

Comment: I will make my best to ping the `polexpr` author to make soon a release of dev version....

Comment: The code has been adapted to the new syntax of polexpr 0.7, which will appear shortly on ctan. Many thanks to the diligent author of polexpr.

Comment: I tested the updated code from this answer with [`polexpr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polexpr) `0.7.2` as appeared on CTAN on 2018/12/09 and it seems to work fine.